# Use pointers in QTextEdit or connect() on Qt-Creator

Tags: c++, linux, qt, c++11, qt-creator

Good morning,
I want QTextEdit dynamically change value when Qtring changed.

for exemple:

```
QString text = "Test2";
ui->OutputConsole->setText(&text);
text = "Test2"; //Value in QTextEdit OutputConsole change dynamically and display "Test2"
```

I was also thinking of using the connect() function,but I do not know how to use it, I found some examples on the internet:

```
QString Text= "Test";
connect(Text, SIGNAL(changeText(QString)), ui->OutputConsole, SLOT(labelChangeText(QString)));
```

I would like to know if it is possible and how to do it ?

Thank you in advance for your help,

Comment: If both `QString` and `QTextEdit` are members of your class, you can create setter method to change both their text at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own class which will wrap your text and signals on text changed

```
class StringWrapper : public QObject
{
   Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit StringWrapper(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    void SetString(const QString& str);

private:
    QString m_str;

signals:
    void TextChanged(QString str);

public slots:
};

void StringWrapper::SetString(const QString &str)
{
    if (str != m_str) {
        m_str = str;
        emit TextChanged(m_str);
    }
}
```

And then connect to your label

```
StringWrapper m_strWrapper;
connect(&m_strWrapper, SIGNAL(TextChanged(QString)), ui->OutpuConsole, SLOT(setText(QString)));
```